# link to dynamic external source in angular

Tags: angular

In AngularJS, I have a link like this:

```
 <a ng-href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{field.location.coordinates[1]}},{{field.location.coordinates[0]}}">{{field.location.address}}</a>
```

How do I create this in Angular 7?  It's a combination of text and dynamic data provided from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[attr.href]` like this

```
<a [attr.href]="'http://maps.google.com/?q=' + field.location.coordinates[1] + ',' + field.location.coordinates[0]">{{field.location.address}}</a>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-attr-href